# What timezone is the amazon detailed billing report generated in?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Amazon provides a detailed billing report CSV which includes fields for the BillingPeriodStartDate and BillingPeriodEnd date. This field is in the format:

`2015/10/31 23:59:59`

However no timezone is attached to the timestamp. Is this time in the AWS accounts timezone or is it UTC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All times are in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC).

[AWS Billing and Cost
Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/awsaccountbilling-aboutv2.pdf)

Comment: That's for the cost explorer, is it true for the exported detailed billing report as well?

Comment: Yes, it is UTC for detailed billing report too. I do not know what "AWS accounts timezone" means. What exactly do you mean by that term?

Comment: The timezone of the account that you created when you signed up to AWS. In other words, if I signed up for AWS and set my location to Sydney, Australia, would those records be created in the Sydney, Australia timezone.